# HTTP service 404 error, json file not found

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, http

I'm setting up translate service in my application by passing json file with certain language to the webpage. After all connections, imports were made i wanted to test it and show in console log fetched data. But after all console log shows me an empty object with 404 not found error

I checked all paths, imports, connections, also added path to 'assets' property in angular.json(tried restart ng serve), but error still existing.

```
   export class TranslateService {
    data:any = {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  use(lang: string): Promise<{}> {
    return new Promise<{}>((resolve, reject) => {
      const langPath = `assets/${lang}.json`;
      this.http.get<{}>(langPath).subscribe(
        translation => {
          this.data = Object.assign({}, translation, {});
          resolve(this.data);
        },
        error => {
          this.data = {};
          resolve(this.data);
        }
      );
    });
  }  

   import { TranslateService } from './translate.service';
   export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private meta: Meta, private cd:    ChangeDetectorRef, private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.use('kz').then(() => {
      console.log(translate.data);
    });
  }
```

I expect object with data inside but getting empty.

Location of files:

```
src
   -app
       --translate.service.ts
       --app.component.ts
   -assets
       --kz.json
```

angular.json:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles/styles.scss"],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["src/styles"]
            },
            "scripts": []
          }
```

Comment: Post the relevant information: the content of your angular.json file, the precise location of your assets folder in your project, and what it contains.

Comment: I added folder tree and angular.json content

Comment: did you replace ``` const langPath = `assets/${lang}.json`;```, ````${lang}``` with correct file name ?

Comment: Yes, even directly renamed to const langPath = "assets/kz.json";. Nothing changed @DilanTharaka